# What is the correct way to configure python output encoding?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, stdout

I am reading utf-8 encoded text from a csv, doing some parsing, and outputting to a text file. I am outputting to the text file indirectly  by using a batch file. Currently I am using print() to output the information to the console, and the batch file is automatically redirecting that information to the output txt file.

I have seen a few answers that say to use:
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')

However, when I use that, I get the following error:
'TTYOutStream' object has no attribute 'reconfigure'

Is this a version problem? I am using 3.11.4, is that answer outdated?

Comment: There is no such class `TTYOutStream` in CPython. What is your Python environment? Can you tell us the `type(sys.stdout).__module__` and the `__import__(type(sys.stdout).__module__).__file__`?

Comment: "Currently I am using print() to output the information to the console, and the batch file is automatically redirecting that information to the output txt file." - okay, and **what happens** when you do that - just by itself, without trying to use `sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')`? **How is that different** from what is supposed to happen? When you used `sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')`, what **concrete problem were you trying to solve**?

Comment: @wim An internet search vaguely suggests that this class might have something to do with Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error, or a similar one if opening your script with
Jupyter, instead of Python directly. (Although in my version of Jupyter, the object was named "OutStream" not "TTYOutStream" - maybe you are in a similar environment, like Google-Collabe instead).

The notebook technology have to replace the stdout with specialized objects so that it can operate its magic - and it is little likely it can be reliably redirected to another file.

You could simply run your script with Python3 instead of Jupyter, or other environment removed from the shell, like Python's own "Idle" - and your sys.stdout will be a regular TextIoWrapper. However, as the remaining of the answer details, it can be tricky to reconfigure properly under Windows (and will nonetheless work straightforward, no re-configure needed under other OSes).

In other words: under Jupyter or other controled enviroments, sys.stdout is replaced by an object that does not feature all methods "normal" sys.stdout does, and that includes "reconfigure".

So, to best achieve your results, just open a new, fresh file, and pass it explicitly to your print statements, without depending from output redirections to record your results:

```
...
mystdout = open("myfile.csv", "wt", encoding="utf=8")
...
print(my_data, file=mystdout)
```

This will give you better and more controlable results than trying to redirect the output of a stream you are not in control of. If for some reason that can't be done, I have some more exploring bellow - but your mileage may vary:

For Python being called from a shell stdout will usually be a `_io.TextIOWrapper` - when redirecting the `tty`, the call to `sys.stdout.isatty`  will return False.

Of course under a Unix environment, like any Linux or MacOS, your encoding will be utf-8 by default - so I experimented under Windows with cmd, powershell and git bash: while none of those would replace sys.stdout with a `TTYOutStream` and always have te `.reconfigure` method available, when redirecting the output

The results of forcing the output with a call to `sys.stdout.reconfigure` would vary, and only really worked in window's git BASH with serious emojibake under `cmd` and PowerShell

Otherwise, a non-replaced stdout will also allow you to bypass the text encoding mechanisms and write raw bytes by calling `sys.stdout.buffer.raw.write(...)`  (instead of "print") - and then you can manually encode any text to utf-8 prior to writing it there - In order to keep using the `print` function you can recreate a file-wrapper object with an explicit encoding like bellow, and pass it to the `file` argument to your `print` calls:

```
import sys, os
mystdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), "wt", encoding="utf-8")

print("Alô mundo", file=mystedout)
```

If your fake stdout does not have a  "fileno()" as well, you can further try to hardcode it to "1" in the call above, and also replace sys.stdout with your "custom" stdout stream. It probably will still fail, if your enviroment is indeed wrapping the call to your Python script and passing a custom Python object in place of the stdout  - the first hint in this answer: just `open` a file from Python and write to it, will always work, though.

```
...
mystdout = os.fdopen(1, "wt", encoding="utf-8")
sys.stdout = mystdout
...
print("alô mundo")
```

Comment: Please don't guess about stuff; wait for an MRE and a clear description of the thought process (e.g. why OP is trying this method and what went wrong *without* it).

Answer (score -1):

I can confirm that in Python 3.11, `sys.stdout.reconfigure()` doesn't work.

An easy workaround is to use `open()` instead:

```py
with open("file.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write("write any sort of utf-8 text here")
```

**Edit:**
It turns out I was wrong—`stdout` is given the `TextIO` type as a type hint, but it's able to use any `TextIOWrapper` method (unless the stream has been overridden). This is explained in a comment in `sys.pyi`:

```py
# TextIO is used instead of more specific types for the standard streams,
# since they are often monkeypatched at runtime. At startup, the objects
# are initialized to instances of TextIOWrapper.
#
# To use methods from TextIOWrapper, use an isinstance check to ensure that
# the streams have not been overridden:

if isinstance(sys.stdout, io.TextIOWrapper):
    sys.stdout.reconfigure(...)
```

Comment: in which enviroment did you try this? 
I've just checked Python 3.11 under Linux and Python 3.12 b1 under windows: `sys.stdout.reconfigure` is always there. (Although it won't yield the expected results in some windows environments)